# Delete Directory With a Specific Sub Directory Name From The Main Directory

Tags: c#, asp.net, directory, subdirectory

I have a main directory with many sub directories. 
Does anyone know how to delete the sub directory with directory name 'Directory 1' from the main directory?

This is my codes currently:

```
if (Directory.Exists(MainDirectory))
            {
                foreach (DirectoryInfo SubDir in new DirectoryInfo(MainDirectory).GetDirectories())
                {
                        SubDir.Delete(true);                      
                }
            }
```

My codes currently will delete all the sub directories in the main directory instead of just sub directory with directory name 'Directory 1'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this;

```
if (Directory.Exists(MainDirectory))
{
    List<DirectoryInfo> directories = new DirectoryInfo(MainDirectory).GetDirectories().ToList();

    foreach (DirectoryInfo SubDir in directories)
    {
         if (SubDir.Name.Equals("Directory 1", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
             SubDir.Delete(true);
    }
}
```

First get all the sub directories to list and loop the list instead of looping `new DirectoryInfo(MainDirectory).GetDirectories()` which will create array of sub directories each time of loop.

Comment: hi @Irshad , it works well! :) Thanks for your help and explanation!